# Preserving decimals when reading from files in php

Tags: php

So I have a text document which is literally as follows

```
7
3
100
200.
300
```

and my code for reading from the file is:

```
$file = fopen("example.txt","r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

`$first = "" + fgets($file);
$second = "" + fgets($file);
$answers = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < $second ; $x++) {
    $answers[$x] = "" + fgets($file);
}
    echo(answers[1]);`

this results in `200` being printed out to the screen.

How do I preserve the decimal point in the line that outputs `200` but whose actual value is `200.` ?

Comment: `"" + fgets($file);` --- why do you do this? It implicitly converts both operands to numbers

Comment: It turns everything into a number?

Comment: then you get what you get `200.` is a string, whereas `200` is a number it represents. You're confusing the data with its representation. If you want the strings to stay as they were - leave them as strigns

Comment: I don't follow. I want to get `200.`

Comment: So I have already mentioned - that if you want to have a string - leave it as a string, don't convert it into a number

Comment: If I just do fgets($file) it still doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an issue explanation. Does it output "I don't work" to the screen or we are supposed to guess what you get?

Comment: It doesn't work as in it outputs `200`, not `200.`

Comment: Your provided code doesn't have any function that could produce an output. How are we supposed to know how exactly you output it? So append it with how you output the data and change it to the actual state (without `"" +` garbage)

Comment: I do it through `echo(answers[1]);` in the line below the last line displayed in the question

Comment: I took your code (I removed the pointless `"" + `) and that's what it output: `100 200. 300`

Comment: that's weird. What version of php are you using?

Comment: update the question with the **actual code** (including `echo`) that doesn't work, this behaviour wouldn't change since php 4.0.0

Comment: So you haven't removed `"" +` and expected something to change? Are you sure you read what I'm saying?

Comment: sorry I removed that in my actual code. I didn't copy paste the new code, just added in my echo statement by hand into the question

Comment: "I didn't copy paste the new code" --- so you want us to continue guessing?

Comment: You haven't. Now it's syntactically incorrect. It becomes annoying, really

Comment: how so? This code works for me

Comment: "This code works for me" --- how the variable without `$` could be valid in `echo(answers[1]);` ???

Comment: oh yeah just saw that. My bad. Thanks a lot for helping me out. The reason why it was working for me is because the page was cached on my end. Once again thanks a bunch- everything works now!

Comment: And I doubt you care, but if you want to add an answer that explains what you did, I'd upvote it and mark it as the one I liked because you really were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you've been using a weird construction:

```
"" + $var
```

what it does as a result is implicitly converts both operands to numbers. Assuming `$var = '200.';` the result of this expression will be `float(200)`.

The `200.` is not a number, but a string representation of a number. So if you want to leave it as it is - just don't convert it into a number.